# Disabling right-click for not yet loaded content

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to disable people from downloading the images from my bootstrap image gallery, but since it isn't loaded until it shows up it is still clickable. If I disable right-click for body instead of img, then it works fine.. But I don't want to disable the whole body.

I'm using this gallery (the full-size version):
https://blueimp.github.io/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/

The JQuery that I'm using to disable it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("img").on("contextmenu",function(e){
   return false;
   }); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) instead of waiting for `$(document).ready`:

```
$(document).on("contextmenu","img",function(e){
   return false;
});
```

That said, please keep in mind that it's not hard to use the browser's DOM debugger to download your images anyway. Disabling right-clicking is more of a nuisance than a solution, and (in my opinion) you're better off just accepting that anything on the web can and will be downloaded by anyone who wants it.

Comment: Well at least the average user wont be able to download them ;) .. thanks